# PHP SOAP Client VersionMismatch - Where to look next?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

So I am getting the `SoapFault exception: [VersionMismatch] Wrong Version` from my SOAPClient request in PHP. Here is where it gets interesting however:

- I captured the request both before and after it was sent and put both into  SoapUI to test them and it returns perfectly. Thus ruling out namespace issues referred to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720180/does-this-soap-fault-mean-what-i-think-it-means) (I think).
- I checked the Soap Version and sent it through as a parameter. (It is 1.1 but I tried both anyway) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855653/php-soapclient-version-mismatch?lq=1).
- I checked OpenSSL is installed (it is https wsdl)

I'm out of ideas and open to suggestions as to where one might look next.

Basically the request is working on SoapUI and what appears to be the exact same request is giving the `SoapFault exception: [VersionMismatch] Wrong Version` error via PHP SOAPClient. (Note I can connect to other Webservices).

Thanks

Comment: Long shot: What version of PHP are you running, and specifically the soap extension? If you're on an ancient version, it's possible the extension doesn't support the version you are running?

Comment: Thanks @STLMikey, long shots welcome. Unfortunately it is PHP 5.4 so shouldn't present any problems I think.

Comment: @joesk could you provide WSDL?

Comment: Hi @PiotrOlaszewski apologies but I'm not in a position to publish it. Anything in particular that I could look for in it?